# Individual background color of a QListWidget-item on selection

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside, qlistwidget

I have a list of indidually colored items in a QListWidget as part of a Python3/PySide application. On selection, I would like the items being highlighed using some color while maintaining their respective background, i.e.

[image: desired display]

and not a full-colored version as depicted in the following image

[image: current display]

The items which are mainly distinguished by means of the colors (background or not) are rearrangable using dragging. It is important for a user to be able to always see what the current selection is.

Using `selection-color: solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 50%);` does not show the desired effect.

I'm not sure how the aspects discussed in [SO:Selected QListWidgetItem without changing text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035707/selected-qlistwidgetitem-without-changing-text-color) and even more [How to customize QListWidget with different highlight bar and spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274806/how-to-customize-qlistwidget-with-different-highlight-bar-and-spacing) may apply to my problem. Is it really necessary to add another Widget on top of the list? Is there a way to apply a different brush to an item on selection (using `PySide.QtGui.QListWidgetItem.setBackground(brush)`)? The stylesheets do not seem to help in my case.

Here is the condensed code:

```
import sys
import collections
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        #definition of colors and brushes (for colored backgrounds)
        layers = collections.OrderedDict(
            {1:('greenItem','g'),
             2:('yellowItem','y'),
             3:('mixedItem','m')})
        brushes = {'y': QtGui.QColor(255,200,0),
                   'g': QtGui.QColor(0,  160,0)}
        texSIG = QtGui.QPixmap(200,1)
        texSIG.fill(brushes['g'])
        paint = QtGui.QPainter()
        paint.begin(texSIG)
        paint.fillRect(80, 0, 40, 1, brushes['y'])
        paint.end()
        brushes['m'] = texSIG
        #create list
        self.lst = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.lst.setStyleSheet( """
                                QListWidget:item:selected:active {
                                     background-color:red;
                                }
                                """
                                )
        #comment on styling:
        #background-color on selection is plain red
        #something like "selection-color: solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 50%);" shows no effect

        self.lst.setSortingEnabled(False)
        for idx, d in layers.items():
            newItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem('{:s}'.format(d[0]))
            newItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush( brushes[d[1]] ))
            newItem.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            self.lst.addItem(newItem)
        self.lst.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection))
        self.lst.setDragDropMode(self.lst.InternalMove)
        #setup and show window
        self.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.setMinimumHeight(200)
        self.show()
#create gui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
#create and display main window
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
#return exit code
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do not use QListWidget, use QListView with custom delegate. With QListView it will be done in couple lines of code.